# Demand deposits in the US between 2002-2008 - why no growth?

Tags: money-supply

I just happened to stumble upon the following graph of total demand deposits in the US.

[image]

I was very surprised to see essentially no growth between 2002 and 2008. I had heard that in the same period in the UK the money supply was growing at around 10% per year and I thought that the US had a very similar situation with an enormous housing bubble developing. Surely with all those ever growing mortgages being taken out, the total of demand deposits should have been growing like crazy. I feel like there is something I'm missing.

FYI: I am aware that demand deposits expire as the principal is repaid on existing loans - but surely if house prices were increasing then the rate of demand deposit creation should have been greater than the rate of demand deposit expiry.

Comment: Isn't a demand deposit just a checkings account 
/current account and essentially unrelated to mortgages?

Comment: @Alex: Yes a demand deposit is one and the same thing as a current account/ checking account ... but I thought that the money banks create for mortgages would end up in these kinds of account... where else?

Comment: You may get your mortgage paid out to your current account but immediately send it to the sellers current account. It's extremely unlikely the seller will keep the money at a near zero interest paying account. The buyer needs to pay back the mortgage every month (usually to a designated account that is not a current account with the bank), meaning his/her current account has (large) monthly outflows. Ultimately, a current account is an account for receiving and paying money quickly.